# программное включение громкой связи во время звонка в android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

требуется чтобы при ответе на звонок сразу включался режим громкой связи 
работаю с 26апи (6я версия андроида)
пытался так:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) 
                                      getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
          audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
          audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

но метод не работает
актуален ли он ?
если нет, то есть альтернатива ?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в манифест разрешения:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

И попробуйте также добавить небольшую задержку (полсекунды) перед включением громкой связи:

```
try {
     Thread.sleep(500);
} catch (InterruptedException e) { ... }

//Activate loudspeaker
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)                                     
 .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Comment: разрешения все есть
попробовал поставить задержку, но не помогло